# CloudFormation Template doesnt pick KeyPair

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I have created below four resources successfully using the `Cloud Formation Template (CFT)`:

1. VPC
2. Subnet
3. InternetGateway
4. AttachGateway

Now, I am trying to create a security group with EC2 instance, here is the code.

```
  Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
  Properties:
      GroupDescription: Allow http and ssh to client host
      VpcId:
         Ref: InsuranceVPC
      SecurityGroupIngress:
      - IpProtocol: tcp
        FromPort: 80
        ToPort: 80
        CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
      - IpProtocol: tcp
        FromPort: 22
        ToPort: 22
        CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
      SecurityGroupEgress:
      - IpProtocol: tcp
        FromPort: 80
        ToPort: 80
        CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0

Ec2Instance: 
  Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
  Properties: 
    ImageId: "ami-08706cb5f68222d09"
    KeyName: 
      Ref: "DevOpsAutomation"
    NetworkInterfaces: 
      - AssociatePublicIpAddress: "true"
        DeviceIndex: "0"
        GroupSet: 
          - Ref: "InsuranceSecurityGroup"
        SubnetId: 
          Ref: "InsuranceSubnet"
```

But, when I use the Key parameter in (CFT, as shown above, code) which is my key present in the same region of the resources, my CFT stack fails with below error:

`Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies [DevOpsAutomation] in the Resources block of the template`
`note: DevOpsAutomation is my keyname`

Steps I validated:

1. CFT template resources and the key is in the same region
2. deleted and freshly created key pair
3. tried to use different key pair
4. I couldn't see an option anywhere to import the key along with the CFT stack so that my EC2 instance can use it.
5. **Even while creating the stack the key DOESN'T appear** (which is visible in `keypair` section) in the `parameter` section of the stack.

My query is, how should I create EC2 instance (as a part of CFT) using the key pair which is present in my AWS account?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the `Ref` in front of the key name. `Ref` is used to reference other resources that have been defined as part of the CloudFormation template. If the key pair already exists, you can simply use the key name.

```
KeyName: "DevOpsAutomation"
```

Comment: Great, happy to help!

Answer (score 2):

I have copied here an example

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: >
  AWS CloudFormation template to create Jenkins server
Parameters:
    KeyName:
        Type: AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName
        Default: ritefit-keypair
Resources:
    JenkinsEC2Instance:
        Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
        Properties:
        KeyName: !Ref KeyName
```

Show us more what have defined KeyName so we can help you what the issue is